# Phoenix channels polyfills

Tags: ecmascript-6, elixir, phoenix-framework

As I went trough the client channel code (inside the phoenix.js file) I saw that it uses ES6. Sample code:

```
let chan = socket.chan("rooms:123", {token: roomToken})
//     chan.on("new_msg", msg => console.log("Got message", msg) )
//     $input.onEnter( e => {
//       chan.push("new_msg", {body: e.target.val})
//           .receive("ok", (message) => console.log("created message", message) )
//           .receive("error", (reasons) => console.log("create failed", reasons) )
//           .after(10000, () => console.log("Networking issue. Still waiting...") )

this.onError( reason => {
      this.socket.log("channel", `error ${this.topic}`, reason)
      this.state = CHAN_STATES.errored
      this.rejoinTimer.setTimeout()
    })
```

That means that it won't run natively in IE and Safari (ate least). Shouldn't I use some kind of polyfills?
What's the best approach/polyfill?
Also, I'm under the impression that polyfills cover classes/let/...but not arrow functions/new string interpolation. Should I change those myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ES6 adds new syntax to the language, there is no way to polyfill arrow functions.

However, when creating a new application, Phoenix installs a library called [Brunch](https://brunch.io) which is used for combining assets. It includes a wrapper for [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) which will transpile ES6 to JavaScript that will run in the browser.

If you look at `priv/static/app.js` (the compiled output) instead of `web/static/app.js` (the source) then you will see it does not have the new ES6 syntax.

One thing you may find if you use certain functions then you may need to include `babel-polyfill.js` which you can read about at https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/caveats/

This was introduced in Phoenix 0.10.0 and you can read more about it in the announcement post http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.14.0/blog/phoenix-0100-released-with-assets-handling-generat

Comment: Understood. Thank you again.